# Azure function: Date only parameter in automatic OpenAPI spec

Tags: c#, azure-functions, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm creating an in-process Azure function in .net 6 using [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/main/docs/enable-open-api-endpoints-in-proc.md) to enable automatic OpenAPI/Swagger specification.

I need to send in a date (without time) as a part of the path, like this:

```
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "history/{itemId}/{channel}/{fromDate}/{toDate}")] HttpRequest req,
```

I can add a paramter like this:

```
[OpenApiParameter(name: "fromDate", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Required = true, Type = typeof(DateTime), Summary = "From date", Description = "The date to fetch prices from. Only the date part is used (time is ignored).", Visibility = OpenApiVisibilityType.Important)]
```

but it will result in the type string($date-time) for "fromDate" in the spec.

Is it possible to make it a date-only?

Comment: Try with `DateOnly` type instead of `DateTime` in `[OpenApiParameter(name: "fromDate", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Required = true, Type = typeof(DateTime), Summary = "From date", Description = "The date to fetch prices from. Only the date part is used (time is ignored).", Visibility = OpenApiVisibilityType.Important)]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented an [IDocumentFilter](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/issues/537#issuecomment-1491200865) to alter the format of the DateTime parameter to date which gave me the correct type in swagger.json. However I could not try it out in the Swagger UI. The parameter could not be parsed. I believe it has to do with [lacking support json deserialization of DateOnly in .net 6](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2319#issuecomment-1310175442).

Until someone proves it is possible, I will mark this as answered (and not possible to do).

Answer (score 0):

***I have created a simple .NET 6.0 Azure Function and reproduced your requirement in my environment.***

I tried with the code you have provided (having `DateTime` type)

```cs
[OpenApiParameter(name: "fromDate", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Required = true, Type = typeof(DateTime), Summary = "From date", Description = "The date to fetch prices from. Only the date part is used (time is ignored).", Visibility = OpenApiVisibilityType.Important)]
```

As per my observation, it was expecting in *DateTime* format.

[image]

> Is it possible to make it a date-only?

Yes, you can use [DateOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/how-to-use-dateonly-timeonly#the-dateonly-structure) type instead of `DateTime`. I tried in my environment and it worked :

```cs
 [OpenApiParameter(name: "fromDate", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Required = true, Type = typeof(DateOnly), Summary = "From date", Description = "The date to fetch prices from. Only the date part is used (time is ignored).", Visibility = OpenApiVisibilityType.Important)]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with DateOnly and it excluded the "type" for the parameter in the swagger.json. I think that is why you don't see any type in the UI below the parameter name. If I use NSwagStudio to generate an API client it creates variables of "object" type. So I guess that it could work but only if the object-variable is parsed correctly. i would like a solution where the swagger says the type is "string($date)".